# how to turn off facebook signed_request in the page tab?

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook app that gets its contents from nationbuilder.com. When the signed_request is truned off, the app works fine, but when it's turned on I get a 404 error. I think it's because nationbuilder doesn't allow POST requests to their site from an outside source. So it's fine with me as long as I can turn off the signed request in the app settings. My question is, how do I turn off the signed_request for the facebook page tab? The settings for the signed_request only apply to the app, but it doesn't affect the page tab. So, is there any way to make facebook not to send the POST request to nationbuilder? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no possibility to turn off the signed_request only for Page Tab. I guess NationBuilder should allow this use case.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

If the NationBuilder page is public, you could, scrape your NB content by creating  an API, and alternative page, using  Kimono Labs. http://www.kimonolabs.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook currently does not support a feature where you can turn off the signed_request. The same problem of not accepting POST request rises when you try to load content from Amazon s3, again, POST request are not accepted.

A possible workaround is to have a php based proxy-like page which loads the content from NationBuilder and add that page to the Facebook tab.